# No result string when a file is uploaded to PHP server using C# client

Tags: c#, php, rest

I have a PHP code to upload a file from C# client:

PHP:

```
<?php

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$name");
}
?>
```

C#:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
byte[] result = Client.UploadFile("https://products.softsolutionslimited.com/php.new/marketing/upload.php", "POST",
                                  @"c:\file.zip");
string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
```

It is working fine and the file is successfully uploaded, but I get null response  in `byte[] result` variable. Can I get a response from UploadFile call? Otherwise I have check if file exists and match size etc. with this code:

```
WebRequest Request = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://products.softsolutionslimited.com/php.new/marketing/Author.png");
Request.Method = "HEAD";
Request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
using (HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse())
{
    if (Response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error");
        return;
    }
}
```

But it seems an extra overhead if I can not get a direct result from UploadFile call.

And is it possible to get a URL path of saved file on server as result of API call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`WebClient.UploadFile` returns the body of the response from the HTTP request.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.uploadfile?view=netframework-4.8)  Currently your PHP code produces no output.

Simply return some kind of output from your PHP code and you'll see it in the response.  It could be any confirmation you like.  For example:

```
echo $name;
```

(Personally I'd prefer to use JSON for my API requests/responses, but the overall concept is the same.)

Comment: Thanks.Is it possible to pass an argument/parameter along/before/after the Client.UploadFile? such as a password? because I don't want any unauthorized user to use the call to my server to corrupt data and only authorized users of the software can make a call. And i also want to pass a value like user-id so  that the server can save file at appropriate folder path of user

Comment: @ComputerUser: How to authenticate a user in your server-side code, and provide that authentication from your client-side code, is an entire subject in and of itself.  A quick Google search finds what appears to be an in-depth tutorial here: https://www.codeofaninja.com/2018/09/rest-api-authentication-example-php-jwt-tutorial.html  There are many other resources to find as well.  Granted, you could always do something much simpler and just have username and password form fields, sacrificing a bit of security of a bit of simplicity.  It's up to you.

Answer (score 2):

The WebClient UploadFile depends on an HTTP post method so basically it's possible.
But you are not returning anything in your php code.

To return a text in php

```
echo 'text to return';
```

Comment: Thanks.Is it possible to pass an argument/parameter along/before/after the Client.UploadFile? such as a password? because I don't want any unauthorized user to use the call to my server to corrupt data and only authorized users of the software can make a call. And i also want to pass a value like user-id so  that the server can save file at appropriate folder path of user

Comment: You can pass what you like